# Collection view selected cell background view color not changing in IOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, colors, uicollectionview, ios15

When the collection view cell is selected, cell background view and the other labels in that cell should change color. The below code is working for below ios 15. If i change didSet to willSet in the below code, it is working for ios 15 but its not working below ios 15. Is there a solution to change the color for the selected custom cell? I am adding the collection view delegate and datasource methods code as well.

```
 override var isSelected: Bool{

        didSet{
            if self.isSelected
            {
                super.isSelected = true
                lblName.textColor = .white
                cellBGView.backgroundColor = .themeColor
                cellInfoBtn.tintColor = .white

            }
            else
            {
                super.isSelected = false
                lblName.textColor = .themeColor
                cellBGView.backgroundColor = .white
                cellInfoBtn.tintColor = .themeColor
            }
        }
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
 { 
selectIndex = indexPath.row 
let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionCell 
selectedIndexPath = indexPath 
selectIndexSec = indexPath.section 
collectionView.reloadData() 
}

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell { 
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionCell cell.cellInfoBtn.tag = indexPath.row 
cell.cellInfoBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(infoBtnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside) 
if selectIndex == indexPath.row { cell.isSelected=true } 
else { cell.isSelected=false }
 return cell 
}
```

I tried the above code and i need to find a common solution for old version as well as version above 15. If there is already an answer exists, please redirect me to it.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a lot of extra work.

A `UICollectionView` tracks its own selections with `.indexPathsForSelectedItems`, so there is no need for the additional tracking with your `selectedIndexPath` and `selectIndexSec`.

Also, if you're overriding `isSelected`, there's no need to call `.reloadData()`.

Here's a complete example -- I added the `lblName` and `cellBGView` but not the button:

```
class AutoHighlightCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let lblName = UILabel()
    let cellBGView = UIView()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        lblName.textAlignment = .center
        
        [cellBGView, lblName].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        cellBGView.addSubview(lblName)
        contentView.addSubview(cellBGView)
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            cellBGView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            cellBGView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            cellBGView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            cellBGView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            lblName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellBGView.topAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            lblName.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellBGView.leadingAnchor, constant: 24.0),
            lblName.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellBGView.trailingAnchor, constant: -24.0),
            lblName.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellBGView.bottomAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            
        ])
        
        contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        
        // set default non-selected properties
        lblName.textColor = .blue
        cellBGView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
    }
    
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            lblName.textColor = isSelected ? .white : .blue
            cellBGView.backgroundColor = isSelected ? .systemGreen : .yellow
        }
    }
    
}

class AutoHighlightCollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    let instructionLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.text = "Tap Here"
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let fl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        fl.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 80, height: 50)
        fl.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: fl)

        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        instructionLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(instructionLabel)

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 80.0),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80.0),
            
            instructionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.bottomAnchor, constant: 60.0),
            instructionLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            instructionLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
        ])
        
        collectionView.register(AutoHighlightCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        
        // so we can see the collectionView frame
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(gotTap(_:)))
        instructionLabel.addGestureRecognizer(t)
        instructionLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AutoHighlightCell
        c.lblName.text = "\(indexPath)"
        return c
    }

    @objc func gotTap(_ g: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        var s = "Tap Here\n\n"
        if let pth = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first {
            s += "Selected Path: \(pth)"
        } else {
            s += "No Item Selected"
        }
        instructionLabel.text = s
    }
    
}
```

When run, it will look like this:

[image]

If you tap "Tap Here" before selecting a cell, you'll see:

[image]

after selecting a cell:

[image] [image]

Notice that when you scroll the cells in and out of view, the "Selected" state is maintained by the collection view, and the cell's UI is updated in `override var isSelected` ... no need to worry about any of that in `cellForItemAt` or in `didSelectItemAt`